# Laravel Relationship is actually trigger mysql?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

```
class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * Table name
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'products';

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function buyerSupplier()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Buyer', 'buyer_id');
    }
}
```

Above is example code, if I call `$this->buyerSupplier()->get()` will it run MySQL?

Please, someone, tell me how this Laravel relationship is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **Yes** Laravel runs mysql queries behind the scene, here is a brief description from `Laravel` Official documents,

**Laravel's database query builder provides a convenient, fluent interface to creating and running database queries. It can be used to perform most database operations in your application and works on all supported database systems.
The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding to protect your application against SQL injection attacks. There is no need to clean strings being passed as bindings.**

And about the relationships queries Laravel uses `Eloquent`:

**Eloquent relationships are defined as methods on your Eloquent model classes. Since, like Eloquent models themselves, relationships also serve as powerful query builders, defining relationships as methods provides powerful method chaining and querying capabilities.**

And for more details about how to choose between relationships methods 
read more from [Laravel Official Documents](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)